# NestJs + TypeORM injected repository becomes undefined

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a code that gets `Requisition` data from an external system like so:

```js
init() {
  const requisitionData = this.loginMb().pipe(
    map(response => response.data.token),
    switchMap(loginData => this.getRequisitions(loginData)),
    map(response => response.data),
  );
  requisitionData.subscribe(this.processData);
}
```

Here is `processData()`

```js
processData(response: any) {
  const requisitions = response.content.data;
  for (const p of requisitions) {
    const req = new Requisition(); // Requisition is the TypeORM entity
    req.title = p.title;
    req.reference = p.reference;
    // other fields 

    this.repo.save(requisition);
  }
```

Here's the constructor

```js
@Injectable()
export class RequisitionSync {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Requisition) private readonly repo: Repository<Requisition>,
    private readonly httpService: HttpService,
  ) {}
```

The problem is inside `processData()`, `this.repo` becomes `undefined`. If I do `console.log(this.repo)`  inside `init()`, it will not be `undefined`.

Comment: I believe this is because `subscribe` has a different lexical `this` than the class itself. What happens if you just `console.log(this)` in the `processData` method?

Comment: It outputs `SafeSubscriber { ... `, here's the whole thing: https://pastebin.com/s1zPFBfh

Comment: Just as I thought, the subscribe has a different lexical `this` than the class.

Comment: One question, shouldn't `processData` be an `async` function?

Comment: I'm actually not sure about this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the lexical binding of `this` is different in the class versus in the subscribe method, you'll need to find some other way to manage the function. If possible, I would suggest using one more `map` or a `mergeMap` and running your `this.processData` in it, then subscribing afterwards to let the events transpire as they will, essentially creating the callchain as

```js
init() {
  const requisitionData = this.loginMb().pipe(
    map(response => response.data.token),
    switchMap(loginData => this.getRequisitions(loginData)),
    map(response => response.data),
    map(this.processData), // or mergeMap(data => this.processData(data)), your choice
  );
  requisitionData.subscribe();
}
```

Comment: This worked! I used the `map()` way because `mergeMap` seem to be expecting a return

Comment: Perfect, I'll update the answer. Wasn't sure what your exact use case would be